# Compare two arrays and connect it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, foreach

I have two arrays as `types` and `defaultTypes`. I need to display `types`  with default values array `defaultTypes`.

```
 const types = [
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Some value here'
    },
    {
        Id: 3,
        Name: 'Some value here'
    },
    {
        Id: 4,
        Name: 'Some value here'
    }
 ];

 const defaultTypes = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Default value 1'
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Default value 2'
    }
 ]
```

If in `types` does not exist some of default types (in this case Id: 1 does not exist in the `types` array). I need to add that object in `types` array.
Expected result will be:

```
 const expectedTypes = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: '-'
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Some value here'
    },
    {
        Id: 3,
        Name: 'Some value here'
    },
    {
        Id: 4,
        Name: 'Some value here'
    }
 ];
```

Objects with Ids 1 and 2 always need to be in expectedTypes.

Comment: `let arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2]` array concat.

Comment: Not that, look at the Name prop on expectedTypes array.

Comment: any chance your arrays could be converted to JS objects with key->value map? Then you could use `Object.assign()` to simply merge them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const expectedTypes = types.concat(
  defaultTypes.filter(
    type => !types.some(t => t.Id == type.Id)
  ));
```

explanation: basically what you want is `types` + stuff in `defaultTypes` that are not in `types` already.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```js
let types = [{
    Id: 2,
    Name: 'Some value here'
  },
  {
    Id: 3,
    Name: 'Some value here'
  },
  {
    Id: 4,
    Name: 'Some value here'
  }
];

const defaultTypes = [{
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'Default value 1'
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    Name: 'Default value 2'
  }
];

defaultTypes.forEach(dt => {
  if (!types.some(t => t.Id === dt.Id)) {
    types.push(dt);
  }
});

types = types.sort((a, b) => a.Id - b.Id);
console.log(types);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and try

```
var _ = require('lodash');
defaultTypes.forEach(type => {
  if (!_.find(types, { Id: type.Id })) {
    types.push({ Id: type.Id, Name: '-' });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can first use create a `Set` using `map()` which will contain its of elements in `types`.
- Then loop through the `defaultTypes` and check if the `Set` contain the `Id`. If doesn't then `push()` it to `types`
- At the end use `sort()` to order the elements by `Id`

```js
const types = [ { Id: 2, Name: 'Some value here' }, { Id: 3, Name: 'Some value here' }, { Id: 4, Name: 'Some value here' } ]; 
const defaultTypes = [ { Id: 1, Name: 'Default value 1' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Default value 2' } ]

let ids = new Set(types.map(x => x.Id));

defaultTypes.forEach(x => {
  if(!ids.has(x.Id)) types.push(x)
})
types.sort((a,b) => a.Id - b.Id)
console.log(types)
```

#### Purpose Of `Set`

The purpose of `Set` is to make the time complexity liner `O(n)`. If you don't use `Set` you will need to use `some()` on the `types` in each loop. So the time-complexity would be `O(m*n)`

`Set.prototype.has` has time complexity `O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the elements in the wanted order with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get all values as result.

```js
const
    types = [{ Id: 2, Name: 'Some value here' }, { Id: 3, Name: 'Some value here' }, { Id: 4, Name: 'Some value here' }],
    defaultTypes = [{ Id: 1, Name: 'Default value 1' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Default value 2' }],
    result = Array.from([...defaultTypes, ...types]
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.Id, Object.assign({}, m.get(o.Id), o)), new Map)
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```